# How can catch error 401 in RestSharp.Portable?

Tags: xamarin.forms, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp.Portable in my project, I'm trying catch error 401 but the line client.Execute(request) generates an error.

```
    var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
    client.IgnoreResponseStatusCode = false;

    var response = await client.Execute<T>(request);

    if (!response.IsSuccess)
    {
        //Custom Exception using response.StatusCode 
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly. What is the error you get? Provide us with a minimal runnable example.

Comment: "client.IgnoreResponseStatusCode = false;"

Try this:

"client.IgnoreResponseStatusCode = true;"

Refference : https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/issues/61